# Excel 2013: Use macro to copy and subsequently add data from one sheet to another within same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy, append, excel-2013

I have used the various methods pointed out in this forum and none seem to work, so I will try to be more specific.

I have a workbook called LIBRARY.xlsm.

This workbook contains two worksheets: CALCULATOR and CUTS.

The worksheet CALCULATOR contains two tables: INPUT and OUTPUT.

I enter data into INPUT, values are calculated and automatically entered into OUTPUT.

I create a button below OUTPUT with macro to copy data in OUTPUT to worksheet CUTS.

I enter new data into INPUT, which then updates OUTPUT.

Now I want to copy this new data to CUTS without overwriting or deleting previous data.

Since this project is divided into 5 sections, I should end up with five tables in the worksheet CUTS that I can then print out.

The INPUT table encompasses cells A1:M31, which does not matter (I’m not copying this).

The OUTPUT table occupies cells O6:S26. This is the data that needs to be copied.

Placement into worksheet CUTS can start at cell A1 (which means the table will have the range A1:E20). I would like to skip a column and then place the next data set. Thus, the next data set should begin at G1 (G1:K20), then at M1:Q20 and so forth). Maybe only go three tables across and then start next three below (separated by row).

Here is the code tried to use. Problem is, it does not retain the values and it overwrites the previous data.

```
Sub Create_CUTS ()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim sourceRows As Integer

Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("CALCULATOR")
sourceRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sourceSheet.Range("A:A"))
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("O6:S26" & sourceRows)

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim targetRows As Integer

Set targetSheet = Worksheets("CUTS")
targetRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A"))
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetRows + 1 & ":A" & targetRows + 1 + sourceRows)
sourceRange.Copy Destination:=targetRange

End Sub
```

Thank you, everyone
-Grumps

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  The easiest is probably to just reference the usedrange of the target sheet to know where you left off with the last paste.

```
lastUsedRow = targetSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastColumnUsed = targetSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Then you just add a column or row and paste the table in the new location.  If the column count is 22 or greater, add a row and paste at "A" and the `lastUsedRow + 2`.  There is some potential for this to be wrong if the sheets are saved with cells that are empty, but excel reads them as "used" (somehow people I work with manage to do this all the time, I don't even know how they do it).  It sounds like this is something that users won't be manipulating, so I wouldn't think that would be a problem, but if it is a possible problem for you, you can use a loop to find the next empty cell instead of using the built in "usedrange" collection.